# Display new query results on button click php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a page that displays a query result on load. there is also a date range selector, which when selected has to run the same query and display the updated results.
The page loads perfectly, but when i select the date range and click the button, nothing happens. Here is the code and the image of the page. I am a newbie in php and html, learning by building a web application. So please excuse if my question is very basic and dumb.[Screenshot of Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqqMw.jpg)

```html
<html>
   
   <body>
  <div class="container">
   <h1>Welcome <?php echo $login_session; ?></h1><br></br>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="panel panel-black">
     <div class="panel-heading form-inline">
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
         <label class="control-label" for="fromdate">From:</label>
         <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fromdate" name="fromdate">
         <label class="control-label" for="todate">To:</label>
         <input type="date" class="form-control" id="todate" name="todate">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="todate" id="todate" style="width: 10%;" value="Date Run" >Go</button>
        </div>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
     <div class="panel panel-blue">
      <div class="panel-heading">
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-9 text-justify">
         <div class="huge"><strong><?php echo $main_total_pledges; ?></strong></div>
         <div>Total Pledges</div>
        </div>
        ....
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

```
  <?php
   include('session.php');

    if(isset($_POST["todate"])=="Date Run")
            { 
                $main_query = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT count(a.pledge_id) total_pledges, sum(case when processed_status = 'Approved' then 1 else 0 end) approved, sum(case when processed_status = 'Cancelled' then 1 else 0 end) Cancelled, sum(case when processed_status in ('Alien','Single Gift') then 1 else 0 end) Gift, sum(case when processed_status is null then 1 else 0 end) Pending from waysact_source a left join vlc_processed_item b on a.pledge_id = b.pledge_id where a.fundraiser in (select distinct concat(f_firstname,' ',f_lastname) fundraiser from fundraiser where f_company in (select contractor_name from contractor where company_name = '$_SESSION[login_user]')) and a.pledge_date = '2017-06-06'");
                $main_query_result = mysqli_fetch_row($main_query);
                $main_total_pledges = $main_query_result[0];
                ...
            } else
            {
                $main_query = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT count(a.pledge_id) total_pledges, sum(case when processed_status = 'Approved' then 1 else 0 end) approved, sum(case when processed_status = 'Cancelled' then 1 else 0 end) Cancelled, sum(case when processed_status in ('Alien','Single Gift') then 1 else 0 end) Gift, sum(case when processed_status is null then 1 else 0 end) Pending from waysact_source a left join vlc_processed_item b on a.pledge_id = b.pledge_id where a.fundraiser in (select distinct concat(f_firstname,' ',f_lastname) fundraiser from fundraiser where f_company in (select contractor_name from contractor where company_name = '$_SESSION[login_user]'))");
                $main_query_result = mysqli_fetch_row($main_query);
                $main_total_pledges = $main_query_result[0];
                ...
            }

?>
```

Comment: you are using ajax ? if no then where is you form tag which post the values?

Comment: Where is the form element to submit your query ? Inside your html . If you are using AJAX then please show that also.

Comment: First of All you cant set same id like  `id="todate"`

Comment: Can it be done with out using ajax ? i will include the form element and try. Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

You need `<form>` tag to send data. Like

```
<form action="" method="">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <label class="control-label" for="fromdate">From:</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fromdate" name="fromdate">
            <label class="control-label" for="todate">To:</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="todate" name="todate">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="todate" id="todate" style="width: 10%;" value="Date Run" >Go</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First set Your id unique.

```
<button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-success" name = "btnTodate" id = "btnTodate" style = "width: 10%;" value = "Date Run" >Go</button>
```

And Used Ajax like that

```
    $(document).on('click', 'btnTodate', function(){
var dataValue = {setQuery: 1, data: $("#form_ID").serialize()}
$.ajax({
url: 'YOUR_PHP_FILE',
 dataType: "json",
 data: dataValue, success: function (r) {
}})});
```

And You can get all kind of data that you set in your form display here

**YOUR_PHP_FILE.php**

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['setQuery'])) {
$dataAuto = array();
parse_str($_POST['data'], $dataAuto);
if (!empty($dataAuto["todate"])) {
    $main_query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT count(a.pledge_id) total_pledges, sum(case when processed_status = 'Approved' then 1 else 0 end) approved, sum(case when processed_status = 'Cancelled' then 1 else 0 end) Cancelled, sum(case when processed_status in ('Alien','Single Gift') then 1 else 0 end) Gift, sum(case when processed_status is null then 1 else 0 end) Pending from waysact_source a left join vlc_processed_item b on a.pledge_id = b.pledge_id where a.fundraiser in (select distinct concat(f_firstname,' ',f_lastname) fundraiser from fundraiser where f_company in (select contractor_name from contractor where company_name = '{$_SESSION['login_user']}')) and a.pledge_date = '2017-06-06'");
    $main_query_result = mysqli_fetch_row($main_query);
    $main_total_pledges = $main_query_result[0];
} else {
    $main_query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT count(a.pledge_id) total_pledges, sum(case when processed_status = 'Approved' then 1 else 0 end) approved, sum(case when processed_status = 'Cancelled' then 1 else 0 end) Cancelled, sum(case when processed_status in ('Alien','Single Gift') then 1 else 0 end) Gift, sum(case when processed_status is null then 1 else 0 end) Pending from waysact_source a left join vlc_processed_item b on a.pledge_id = b.pledge_id where a.fundraiser in (select distinct concat(f_firstname,' ',f_lastname) fundraiser from fundraiser where f_company in (select contractor_name from contractor where company_name = '{$_SESSION['login_user']}'))");
    $main_query_result = mysqli_fetch_row($main_query);
    $main_total_pledges = $main_query_result[0];

}
die;}
```